# Extend definable types

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am self-studying Pillay's lecture notes on stability theory ([https://www3.nd.edu/~apillay/pdf/lecturenotes.stability.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eapillay/pdf/lecturenotes.stability.pdf)) and having trouble solving Exercise 2.13.

Let $T$ be a complete $L$-theory with models $M \subset N$. Let $p(x) ∈ S(M)$ be a definable type with defining schema $d: \delta(x,y) \mapsto \psi_\delta(y)$. How to prove that $d(N) := \{\delta(x,b):$ for $\delta(x, y) ∈ L$ and $b ∈ N$ such that $N \models d(\delta)(b)\}$ is a complete type over $N$ extending $p(x)$?

This result is used to show that any complete type over a model of a totally transcendental theory has Morley degree 1 in the notes.

My attempt: $p(x)$ is realized by $a$ in a monster model $\overline M$. Consider an elementary embedding $f: N \rightarrow \overline M$ such that $(i: M \rightarrow \overline M) = f \circ (i: M \rightarrow N)$ (does such $f$ exist?). Maybe $d(N) = \{\delta(x,b): \delta(x,f(b)) \in \text{tp}_\overline M(a/f(N))\}$, but I don't think I am right.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a remark about the monster model convention. The point of working with a monster model $\bar{M}$ is that we assume all elements and sets that we consider to live in $\bar{M}$. Furthermore, any models that we consider will be elementary submodels. This can indeed be done exactly because an $f$ like in your question does exist (exercise, use saturation). In this answer I will follow this convention and leave $\bar{M}$ implicit.

We have to prove two things about $d(N)$: namely that it is a *consistent* set of formulas and that it is *complete*.

**Consistent.** Let $\delta_1(x, b_1), \ldots, \delta_n(x, b_n) \in d(N)$. For any $c_1, \ldots, c_n \in M$ such that $M \models d(\delta_i)(c_i)$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$ we have that $\delta_i(x, c_i) \in p(x)$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, which implies $\delta_1(x, c_1) \wedge \ldots \wedge \delta_n(x, c_n) \in p(x)$ and thus $\models \exists x(\delta_1(x, c_1) \wedge \ldots \wedge \delta_n(x, c_n))$ and hence $M \models \exists x(\delta_1(x, c_1) \wedge \ldots \wedge \delta_n(x, c_n))$ as $M$ is an elementary submodel of the monster. We thus have that
$$
M \models \forall y_1 \ldots y_n ( d(\delta_1)(y_1) \wedge \ldots \wedge d(\delta_n)(y_n) \to \exists x(\delta_1(x, y_1) \wedge \ldots \wedge \delta_n(x, y_n)) ).
$$
As $M$ is an elementary submodel of the monster this sentence then also holds in the monster model (or as there are no parameters: is even a consequence of the theory). By assumption we have, for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, that $\delta_i(x, b_i) \in d(N)$ and so $\models d(\delta_i)(b_i)$. From the above it then follows that $\models \exists x(\delta_1(x, b_1) \wedge \ldots \wedge \delta_n(x, b_n))$. We conclude that $d(N)$ is finitely satisfiable and is thus consistent by compactness.

**Complete.** Let $\delta(x, b)$ be any formula with parameters in $N$ (i.e. $b \in N$). We will show that either $\delta(x, b) \in d(N)$n or $\neg \delta(x, b) \in d(N)$. For this we claim that $d(\delta)(y)$ is equivalent to $\neg d(\neg \delta)(y)$. This would indeed be enough, because then there are two cases:

1. $\models d(\delta)(b)$, so $\delta(x, b) \in d(N)$;
2. $\models \neg d(\delta)(b)$, so $\models d(\neg \delta)(b)$ and thus $\neg \delta(b) \in d(N)$.

To verify the claim we let $c \in M$ be arbitrary. Then we have that $M \models d(\delta)(c)$ iff $\delta \in p(x)$ iff $\neg \delta \not \in p(x)$ iff $M \models \neg d(\neg \delta)(c)$. So we see that $M \models \forall y(d(\delta)(y) \leftrightarrow \neg d(\neg \delta)(y))$, and we conclude by using the fact that $M$ is an elementary submodel of the monster.

Comment: I understand that both $M$ and $N$ can be elementarily embedded into $\overline M$ by $f, g$, but I wonder if the following diagram commutes.
$\require{AMScd} $
\begin{CD} M @>i>> N\\ @.     {_{\rlap{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ f}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{4em}{0em}]{}}}} @VVgV\\  @. \overline M \end{CD}
where $i$ is the inclusion map.

Comment: By renaming $\overline M$, $M$ or $N$ becomes an elementary substructure of $\overline M$, but it may not be possible to guarantee that both $M$ and $N$ are elementary substructures of $\overline M$. So $N \models d(\delta)(b)$ is not equivalent to $\models d(\delta)(b)$. Is the definition of $d(N)$ in my question wrong (I misprinted $\models d(\delta)(b)$ as $N \models d(\delta)(b)$)?

Comment: @XiangLi As I said: the point of working with a monster model is that we assume that everything we consider is already in there. So by assumption we have that $N \subseteq \bar{M}$, and this is also what the author means, see page 2. If you really want to work with the diagram: yes, it can be made to commute (see the 'exercise' in my first paragraph), and therefore we may rename the elements in $N$ (and thus in $M$) so that $N$ actually is a subset of $\bar{M}$. Put differently: $g$ is an isomorphism of $N$ onto $g(N)$ so we may as well replace $N$ by $g(N)$ and continue our proof.